# Pickle file becomes corrupted when downloading from S3 via boto

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pickle

Here is my code for downloading a pickle file from an S3 bucket

```py
def download_resource(key: str, dest: str):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    with open(dest, 'wb') as f:
        s3.download_fileobj(BUCKET, key, f)
```

I've actually done this successfully with some pickle files, but in one case I get an `EOFError` when later using:

```py
with open(dest, 'rb') as f:
    x = pickle.load(f)
```

If I instead download the file from S3 manually via the console, the file is not corrupted and I can load it up in Python without the `EOFError`.

Is there any reason this might happen in some cases?

Comment: If you compare the manually downloaded, working file with a non-working one, is the non-working one e.g. obviously truncated at some position?

Comment: @AKX good that you asked. The Python downloaded one is 0 bytes lol

Comment: @AKX don't worry problem is resolved. I think there must have been a delay of some sort. I had just uploaded them, and there are many to download. The first few were all 0 bytes, and the last few were all what I expected. Then when I tried via the console that was later. So I must have gotten misleading messages and assumed it was some other reason.

Comment: Glad you got it solved. :)